# Automatic directory PDF Conversion

Tags: pdf

I need to setup a conversion service for internal user (and internal third party software).

The user (or software agent) should put the file to convert (in doc format) into a given network share then the server should convert it to pdf and delete the original file.
The conversion can be delayed (the task can be scheduled to run every 5 minutes for example)

My infrastructure is Microsoft based but i can easily setup a linux VM if convenient.

I looked into LibreOffice/OpenOffice batch conversion to PDF with no luck
https://superuser.com/questions/17612/batch-convert-word-documents-to-pdfs-free

Many of the given solution requires user interaction, this service should serve also third party software.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your kind replies

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat can automatically create PDFs from files in watched folders. You need the full version, not just the reader.

Comment: My organization has some Adobe professional License so i'll give it a try. Thanks